# appendChild does not properly set parentElement

Tags: javascript, html

I may be misunderstanding the correct usage of this function, but I believe appendChild is working incorrectly in Firefox.  I have a very large script that has worked fine in IE since version 6.  We're now trying to make this script work in all browsers, so I'm starting to test in FF.

Here's some relevant lines from the script, modified for easier reading here:

```
var tempDocFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var tempNewtbody = document.createElement("tbody"); 
trElem = document.createElement("tr");
tdElem = document.createElement("td");

trElem.appendChild(tdElem);
tempDocFragment.appendChild(trElem);
tempNewtbody.appendChild(tempDocFragment);
mytable.appendChild(tempNewtbody);
```

Code like the above runs within a loop that adds between 0 and 1000+ table rows to a table.  This all appears to work fine and the table rows appear in the table.  However, the table rows have an onmouseover event that runs this line of code:

```
alert(this.parentElement);
```

This returns 'undefined' in Firefox, but returns the proper parentElement on IE.  So it appears that Firefox is running the code to append the child elements correctly, but somehow fails to associate any parent with those child elements.  I would appreciate any insight into what I may be doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: you are adding the TR to the fragment, and then the fragment to the tbody - it should be the other way around

Comment: Why are you appending the trs to a document fragment?  Maybe that's what Firefox thinks is the parent?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior; see http://jsfiddle.net/wxQBK/. Can you create a jsFiddle that demonstrates it, and post a link?

Comment: This was originally designed by someone who left the company long ago; I'm just updating portions for cross-browser compatibility.  I can't tell you exactly why they chose to do any particular thing, but I'm only updating what's needed to make it work; we'll save a rewrite for a later time.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parentElement` [is not supported in Firefox < 9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.parentElement). It started life as a non-standard property of elements in IE 4 and has relatively recently been standardized in [DOM4](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#parent-element).

Use `parentNode` instead.

Comment: Thank you; I was sure it was something simple like this.  :)

Answer (score 2):

the standard way is to use `parentNode`, it will work on all browsers

Comment: Nah. `DocumentFragment` works on all browsers, too. (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:document.createDocumentFragment.)

Comment: @ruakh: The problem is Firefox's lack of support for `parentElement`, not `DocumentFragment`.